# Обработчик нажатий на строку textview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Есть фрагмент в котором я подгружаю данные из firebase. Родительский каталог называется "News" У него есть "ребёнок" news1, news2, newsn.. В них содержаться: imageURL(Картинка новости), news_header(Заголовок новости), newsdate(Дата новости) а так же ребёнок news_main(Главная новость) В нём содержится imageURL и news_text. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на новость открывалось новое активити и в нём подгружалась инфа об этой новости. То есть news_main. Я не использую уникальный ключ. Заголовок новости и т.д. грузится в recyclerview. Может кто сталкивался с таким. Как быть?

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<News> news;


public NewsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<News> n)
{
    context = c;
    news = n;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_view, viewGroup, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

    myViewHolder.news_date.setText(news.get(i).getDatenews());
    myViewHolder.news_header.setText(news.get(i).getHeader_news());
    Picasso.get().load(news.get(i).getImageURL()).into(myViewHolder.news_picture);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return news.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView news_date, news_header;
    ImageView news_picture;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        news_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
        news_header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_header);
        news_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_picture);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String idnews;
TextView main_news;
DatabaseReference reference;
TextView news_date;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Intent intent;
ArrayList<News> Nlist;
NewsAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    intent = getIntent();
    idnews = intent.getStringExtra("idnews");

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("News").child(idnews);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           // for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
              //  news_date.setText(news.getDatenews());
                main_news.setText(news.getNews_main());
                Nlist.add(news);
           // }
            adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Nlist);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Что то не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код передачи id:

```
myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Mcontext, NewsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("idnews", news.getIdnews());
            Mcontext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: приложите кусок кода из вашего адаптера

Comment: Код адаптера приложил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в конструкторе `viewholder` добавьте `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`.
в `OnClick(View view)` открывайте новую `activity`.
Если не используете идентификаторы, и у вас не изменяются данные, можете передавать в качестве ключа позицию новости, забрав ее через метод `getAdapterPosition()`. Но лучше, конечно, использовать уникальные идентификаторы. 
Либо передавайте напрямую новость в новую `activity`

Comment: В общем, написал код: Из адаптера передаю значение ключа, а в активности обрабатываю его. Мне только интересно могу ли задать уникальный идентификатор с помощью RANDOM-KEY?

Comment: Потому как что то мне подсказывает что просто id как в sql db не прокатит

Comment: Так же выложу код.

Comment: Если новостей не много, задавайте как random key

Comment: В общем собрал, запустил. При клике на новость получаю ошибку. Код ошибки ссылается на эту строку: main_news.setText(news.getNews_main());

Comment: Думаю что саму бд не правильно собрал...

Comment: Попробую отследить id которые программа получает и передаёт.

Comment: Странно, программа не получает id новости на которую нажимаю...

Comment: У вас ведь ссылка в news2.imageURL у каждой новости разная, зачем вам еще что то уникальное не пойму?

Comment: news.get(getAdapterPosition()).getIdnews() что-то типа такого

Comment: Ссылка на картинку не уникальная. В некотрых новостях будет 1 и та же картинка в некоторых вообще не будет.

Comment: Я написал так: intent.putExtra("idnews", news.getIdnews()); В активности с помощью  intent = getIntent();
        idnews = intent.getStringExtra("idnews"); Встречаю

Comment: Мне просто заполнять не хотелось. Для проверки решил так оставить. Если выбора не останется буду каждой новости уникальный ключ делать...

Comment: Хм, видимо не заметил... id новости я получаю. Но новость не обрабатывается.

Comment: Хоспаде.... Ошибка оказалось мега банальной..... Забыл раскомментировать  указатель на массив Nlist.................

Comment: Ребят, спасибо всем кто помогал)

Comment: Эхххх, рано я обрадовался... Он парсит мне тоже самое что и в другой активности... Думаю проблема в том что я указал final News news = Mnews.get(i); Но без него обработчик нажатий не работает.

Comment: Правда парсит он только ту новость на которую я нажал.